# Importing large datasets into core data, making the relationships in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, relationship

I have a CoreData database which houses around 500.000 stamps and 86.000 series. I have to download them from a web api, which uses JSON. The adding of stamps and series into core data goes with no problem. But I have troubles when making relationships between the two.

[image: My datamodel]
Each stamp has one serie and each serie can have multiple stamps. As seen in the picture of my datamodel above.

I need to make the relationship between the two, efficiently and fast. While I was doing some research I stumbled across this website https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data/ The piece that I'm most interested in:

> A similar problem often arises when establishing relationships between
>   the newly imported objects. Using a fetch request to get each related
>   object independently is vastly inefficient. There are two possible
>   ways out of this: either we resolve relationships in batches similar
>   to how we imported the objects in the first place, or we cache the
>   objectIDs of the already-imported objects. Resolving relationships in
>   batches allows us to greatly reduce the number of fetch requests
>   required by fetching many related objects at once. Don’t worry about
>   potentially long predicates like:
>
> ```
> [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier IN %@", identifiersOfRelatedObjects];
> ```
>
> Resolving a predicate with many identifiers in the IN (...) clause is
>   always way more efficient than going to disk for each object
>   independently. However, there is also a way to avoid fetch requests
>   altogether (at least if you only need to establish relationships
>   between newly imported objects). If you cache the objectIDs of all
>   imported objects (which is not a lot of data in most cases really),
>   you can use them later to retrieve faults for related objects using
>   objectWithID:.
>
> ```
> // after a batch of objects has been imported and saved
> for (MyManagedObject *object in importedObjects) {
>     objectIDCache[object.identifier] = object.objectID;
> }
>
> // ... later during resolving relationships 
> NSManagedObjectID objectID = objectIDCache[object.foreignKey];
> MyManagedObject *relatedObject = [context objectWithID:objectId];
> object.toOneRelation = relatedObject;
> ```
>
> Note that this example assumes that the identifier property is unique
>   across all entity types, otherwise we would have to account for
>   duplicate identifiers for different types in the way we cache the
>   object IDs.

But I have no idea what they mean by that, can someone give some more explanation about this. Preferably in Swift, as that is the language I understand the best and also the language in which I'm creating my app.
Of course other suggestions are also fine. *Note, moving away from CoreData is not an option anymore.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task of making relationship between two objects involves having those two objects at hand. Considering that they have been already created in Core Data, you may execute a fetch request with predicate like

```
@"countryID == %@", countryObjectData[@"id"]
```

and you'll get them. But if you need to establish five hundred thousands relationships, you'll have to execute one million fetch requests. It's slow.

Retrieving an `NSManagedObject` by its `NSManagedObjectID` is significally faster than searching by property value. Before starting parsing you can build a cache of all your Core Data objects by entity in form of `server key -> objectID` pairs.

```
self.cache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:self.managedObjectModel.entities.count];

NSExpressionDescription *objectIdDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
objectIdDescription.name = @"objectID";
objectIdDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
objectIdDescription.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;

NSString *key = @"serverID";

for (NSEntityDescription *entity in self.managedObjectModel.entities) {
    NSMutableDictionary *entityCache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    self.cache[entity.name] = entityCache;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity.name];
    request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    request.propertiesToFetch = @[key, objectIdDescription];
    NSArray *result = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *item in result) {
        id value = item[key];
        NSManagedObjectID *objectID = item[@"objectID"];
        entityCache[value] = objectID;
    }
}
```

Having that cache you can get your objects like this:

```
id serverKey = countryObjectData[@"id"];
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = self.cache[@"Country"][serverKey];
Country *country = [self.context objectWithID:objectID]
```

It's much faster.

When you creating new objects while parsing JSON, you need to add their server key and objectID pair to cache – after obtaining [permanent](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectid/1391691-temporaryid) IDs. Delete that pair from cache when you deleting object.